# POST Call in R using Loop

Tags: r, api, loops, dataframe, post

I am fetching some info from a website after making a POST call. I am passing an ID for which I am fetching the details.
Right now I am doing it with the help of a loop. I have a data frame "df" having all the IDs

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 Result <- GetDetails(df$id[i])
 }

 GetDetails<- function(id) {

 POST Call body
 return(result)
}
```

This code is working fine when I am passing a single ID.
But the problem is that I have 200 IDs and this code is hitting the website 200 times for the details.
Is there any way by which I can passing all 200 ids at once and get the required details for all 200 ids in a single call?

Comment: I think it is possible if the form allows sending files as part of the post request. You have example on post documentation: `POST(b2, body = list(y = upload_file(system.file("CITATION"))))`

Comment: That's completely up to what the website you are POST-ing to supports. If they only have an API endpoint that takes one ID at a time, then you need to call that endpoint 200 times. You would need to ask the people who supply the API endpoint if there is an alternate one where you can request multiple IDs. There's nothing R can do if the API doesn't support it.